# how to fix border-radius in css for a mobile Jquery website

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a select box I tried adding some corner radius to it using the CSS property `border-radius` looks good in most of the android phone . But in one model it has a small defect shown in the picture

[image]

The background color is coming out of the border . The code for the select box are as follow .

**CSS**

```
.ui-select-custom-a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #c0dae7;
    border-radius: 0.71em 0 0 0.71em !important;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: initial;
    min-width: 50px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <select class="ui-select-custom" data-mini="true">
                <option name="im_va" id="im_va" value="0">Venta</option>
                <option name="im_va" id="im_va" value="1" >Alquiler</option>
            </select>
```

**Script**

```
$('.ui-select-custom').parent().addClass('ui-select-custom-a ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon');
```

Any help regarding this will be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-select-custom-a {
background: #c0dae7;
border-radius: 0.71em 0 0 0.71em !important;
min-width: 50px !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
padding-right: 0 !important;
```

}

Should work

Comment: @Bobadew May I know what is causing the problem here ??

Comment: Has this fixed it? Your css for assigning background you only need to pass the color the rest isn't needed

Comment: @bobadew I could not test it because this problem is occurring only in one of the android device ill check it and let you know .